# Tensorflow: parallel for loop results in out-of-memory

Tags: python, parallel-processing, tensorflow

My tensorflow code is like these:

```
for i in range(100):
    Zk = Zk + function_call(...)
```

It seems that tensorflow runs these 100 iterations in parallel, and keeps many temp vectors which have same size with Zk. However, since Zk is a very long vector, this leads to out-of-memory error immediately.

Can anyone give some suggestion on how to force `Tensorflow` perform loop sequentially. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to solve this problem is to use a [`with tf.control_dependencies():`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#control_dependencies) block:

```
Zk = ...
for i in range(100):
    with tf.control_dependencies([Zk.op]):
        Zk = Zk + function_call(...)
```

The `with tf.control_dependencies():` block ensures that the ops created by `function_call()` do not run until the previous value for `Zk` has been computed. This effectively causes the loop iterations to run sequentially.

---

An alternative solution involves using a [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#while_loop) to define the iteration, rather than a Python loop. The `tf.while_loop()` function has a `parallel_iterations` optional argument that allows you to reduce the amount of parallelism between independent iterations of the loop. One advantage of this approach is that it keeps your graph small: the loop would use O(1) nodes rather than O(N) to perform N iterations. However, it can be slightly tricky to re-cast an arbitrary Python `function_call()` as a TensorFlow loop body, so you'll probably find it easier to use `with tf.control_dependencies():` at first.

Comment: Thank you so much.